# how to move first element to last of a linked list in c language?

Tags: c, list, linked-list

i'm trying to take the first element of a linked list and move it to the last position. I did that using this code :

```
            pend=pstart;
            while(pend->next != NULL) // go to the last element
            {
                pend = pend->next;
            }
            pend->next=pstart;
            pend=pstart;
            pstart=pstart->next;
            pend->next=NULL;
```

but it seems that i might be missing something, because i'm not getting the result i want. So, my question is : is this code correct ? if not please help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Could you elaborate a bit on "i'm not getting the result i want"?

Comment: Also, a bit more context is needed to understand the problem, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. You have messed up somewhere else.

The best way to solve such problems is to draw the linked list using boxes (nodes) and arrows (links).

Answer (score -1):

```
        pend=pstart;
        while(pend->next != NULL) // go to the last element
        {
            pend = pend->next;
        }
        pend->next=pstart;
        pstart=pstart->next;
        pend->next->next= null;
```

Comment: That looks to do the exact same thing as the OP's code.

Comment: While this code block might answer the question. Please try to add relevant explanation with the code in order to improve your answer. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer